# How to count number of doubles input simultaneously

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to populate an array with numbers input by the user, but I don't know the number of inputs beforehand. For example: if the user inputs the numbers 6 12 52, I would need to create arr[3] and put those numbers in it, but if the user inputs 4 5 10 11 45, I would need to create arr[5].

An alternative to this would be that since the maximum number of cells I want my array to have is 12, is there a way to put fewer than 12 inputs into array[12] and delete the remaining cells?

This may be an obvious question, but I cannot seem to find any helpful information on the matter.

Thank you for any assistance.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using C++ try a vector. Else you can allocate an array (let's say size 10) and if you need to make it larger use realloc to make it larger (let's say 20) and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in C lack many of the nicer dynamic re-sizing features of other languages. Using an array of size 12 seems like the simplest solution given your constraints. If you truely wanted it to by dynamic you'd need to either count the number of spaces before hand and build an array for that many elements -- `int *args = malloc((space_count+1)*sizeof(int));`. Or you'd need to create an array of some size and `realloc` as you needed more elements.

Here's a [little guide post](http://forum.codecall.net/topic/51010-dynamic-arrays-using-malloc-and-realloc/) that explains the technique more completely.

Answer (score 0):

Before you start to get actual input numbers, ask the user how many he is going to provide and allocate space accordingly.

Comment: This would have to be done very carefully, as the user could be malicious (or neglectful) and provide more inputs than announced, potentially leading to memory corruption.